# Fail at declaring and using variables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, syntax

I'm trying to get all products that have one or more 'instock' variations. I need to do it with SQL query but it returns 'Syntax Error'. I think the problem is with the variables. 
Can anyone help me figure out the issue ?

```
SELECT *, @post_id := ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_status='publish'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN(
        SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent=@post_id AND 
post_type='product_variation'
) AND meta_key='_stock_status' AND meta_value='instock'
    )
```

EDIT: Now, after changing =IN() to IN and EXIST to EXISTS I have not any error, but query returns nothing. When I replace @post_id with any number it works good. What's wrong with that variable?

Comment: Does you mean `EXISTS`?

Comment: Oh really, but it still doesn't work(

Comment: EXIST should be EXISTS and post_id=IN should be post_id IN() .

Comment: Thanks, now i have not any error, but this does not return any row(((